# Can't get a screenshot of UIView to be displayed inside UIImageView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage, uikit

Here's my code to get the screenshot of the view:

```
if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions){
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(pagedScrollView.frame.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
}else{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pagedScrollView.frame.size);
}

[pagedScrollView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
screenshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:screenshotImage];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x, imageView.frame.origin.y, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

I'm 100% sure I have the right frame and the right view - the size of `UIImageView` say about it - but the thing is I can't get my `UIImage` to be displayed on the `UIImageView`.

The `UIImageView` is added on the view and I see a green region on it - but no image inside it, what can be wrong?

I'm using iOS 6 and ARC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I just tested your code running on my view controller's view and the capture and display worked fine. This leads me to believe that `pagedScrollView` is probably nil, or has a zero frame.

Either way, you'll be creating an image from a blank context and then passing it to your image view resulting in there not being any visible image.

Comment: and how about UIImage gets released so fast it doesn't stay there? Is that possible?

Comment: I have a number of those, about 5, and I add them all to `UIScrollView`. And only the first stays there, while I can't see the others.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I've been taking a screenshot of a long `UIScrollView` and I was always taking its first page - it had a lot of pages in it and sometimes the layer had nothing in it. It also turns out that `UIImage` was never released and the memory can effectively store dozens of them.